# How to find out whether Google storage object is live or noncurrent?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

Google Storage documentation tells about [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning). There are two kinds of the object versions: live and noncurrent.

`gsutil` allow listing both noncurrent and live versions using `-a` switch: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list.

Also, I can list all the versions programmatically by supplying [`versions: true` option](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetFilesOptions) to the [`Bucket.getFiles` method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles).

However I have not found any way to programmatically find out whether a particular object version is live or noncurrent. There seems to be no property or method in the [File object](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html) for this.

What is the proper way of finding this out given a `File` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource), there isn't a state for the live/noncurrent version of the objects. You have a generation number per object resource representation.

I assume that you have to apply yourselves an algorithm for this

- Use List API (getFiles) on a single object with the version option to true
- The highest generation is the live version, others are noncurrent
- Except is timeDeleted is populated on the highest generation (timestamp of the live version deletion). Therefore all the version are noncurrent.

Comment: Thank you, `timeDeleted` metadata key seems to be the correct answer. Also, `gsutils ls -L` or `gsutils stat` show the same time as `Noncurrent time`. However, to be accepted, this answer has to be edited a bit, as `timeDeleted` alone is enough without comparing generation numbers.

Comment: Correct, I forgot few words (and corrected). The timeDeleted on the highest version number means all version are noncurrent.

Comment: Thanks. In my code, I'm not listing versions **on a single object**, but rather all the objects in the bucket, with versions. And for each file (object) I'm relying on the `timeDeleted` metadata only.

Comment: By the way, I've found out that the metadata fields are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata).